# Easy nichrome rivet for a newbie?

Tags: repair

I'm a total newb, but I'm learning fast.

Is there any easy way to get this nichrome wire to fasten to the plate below it?  Could I just tuck it underneath the plate, between the mica board?

[image: Nichrome wire lifted away from rivet]

Comment: You could try tucking it under the plate, and if you are lucky the arcing in operation might weld them together. Otherwise it's time to get a new toaster!

Comment: Spot welder! You could make one using an old microwave transformer.

Comment: A steel bolt and nut might work, at least for a while. *Do not use cadmium (bright plated) hardware*, which would release poisonous fumes, and keep parts well clear of metal case. The hardware may eventually loosen from heating/cooling.

Comment: "The Tuck" worked 100%.  Six pieces of toast so far!  Thank you!

Comment: Congrat's for having a working toaster now. But this Q&A-site depends on some qualifications for questions and answers. One is, that repair questions are off-topic because it is so unlikely that later readers will derive some use from it. Why? Defects are so different for millions of appliances out there. How likely is it, someone with a toaster with exactly the same condition searches this site for a solution? I bet it's one in a million over a year.

Answer (score 1):

Tucking it between that silver tongue and the mica board worked great!

So far, 6 pieces of toast and no fires.